# Separate an object with a mesh face

Tags: modeling

so I have this car model that I want to separate the rear spoiler. As you can see in the linked pictures, I have selected and duplicate faces that I want to separate it from. I know how to split it with a plane using the bisect tool, but in this case I want to maintain the shape of the rear spoiler.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure waht you mean to be honest. The first image appears to show by the outline that the car is a single object and the second one that the spoiler assembly is a single object so presumably you've duplicated it successfully and converted it into a seperate object using 'P' in Edit mode.

Comment: The car is one object with the spoiler... In the second pictures, i selected a couple of faces from the trunk to separate the spoiler but it's still attached... Hopefully it's more clear

Comment: If you go into Edit mode, hover the mouse over the spoiler and hit Ctrl-L is just the spoiler hilighted? If so you can just hit 'P' > Seperate > Selection, go back into Object mode and the spoiler will be a seperate object. If that doesn't work I suggest you share your file (https://blend-exchange.com/help ) and someone here should be able to have a look and see what's going on.